# How do you setup a virtual IP on a Linux cluster?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cluster, linux-networking, failovercluster

I am having some problems setting a virtual IP and Linux (Ubuntu) cluster and I am hoping someone can help. This is the first node cluster I've tried to setup and I am not finding many resources in regards to this issue.

I am going through this guide to setup DRBD/Virtual IP on Ubuntu: https://wiki.edubuntu.org/ClusterStack/Natty#HA_Virtual_IP_Address

But I am having some major problems setting up the virtual IP. I've setup DRBD and it syncs and loads without any problems. But when I try to add the Virtual IP I get the following error message

```
pengine: [843]: info: native_color: Resource virtual_ip cannot run anywhere
```

Here is my CRM config:

```
node EOA-MAIL-IB-1
node EOA-MAIL-IB-2
primitive drbd_eoa ocf:linbit:drbd \
    params drbd_resource="eoa-ib" \
    op monitor interval="15s"
primitive fs_drbd ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem \
    params device="/dev/drbd0" directory="/mnt" fstype="ext4" \
    meta target-role="Stopped"
primitive virtual_ip ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 \
    params ip="192.168.1.254" nic="eth1" \
    op monitor interval="30s"
group res_group fs_drbd virtual_ip
ms ms_drbd drbd_eoa \
    meta master-max="1" master-node-max="1" clone-max="2" clone-node-max="1$
colocation mnt_on_master inf: res_group ms_drbd:Master
order mount_after_drbd inf: ms_drbd:promote res_group:start
property $id="cib-bootstrap-options" \
    dc-version="1.0.8-042548a451fce8400660f6031f4da6f0223dd5dd" \
    cluster-infrastructure="openais" \
    expected-quorum-votes="2" \
    stonith-enabled="false" \
    no-quorum-policy="ignore" \
    last-lrm-refresh="1336683121"
```

Here is the output of "crm resource list":

```
Master/Slave Set: ms_drbd
 Masters: [ EOA-MAIL-IB-1 ]
 Slaves: [ EOA-MAIL-IB-2 ]
Resource Group: res_group
 fs_drbd    (ocf::heartbeat:Filesystem) Stopped
 virtual_ip (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2) Stopped
```

I have two NICS installed on both servers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was a configuration issue with the CRM config file, go figure. :)

Below is the updated/correct config file for anyone else encountering this type of issue:

```
node EOA-MAIL-IB-1
node EOA-MAIL-IB-2
primitive drbd_eoa ocf:linbit:drbd \
    params drbd_resource="eoa-ib" \
    op monitor interval="120s" \
op start interval="0" timeout="240s" \
op stop interval="0" timeout="100s"

primitive fs_drbd ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem \
    params device="/dev/drbd0" directory="/mnt/eoacluster" fstype="ext4" \
    op start interval="0" timeout="60s" \
op stop interval="0" timeout="60s"

primitive mysql_eoa ocf:heartbeat:mysql \
    params config="/etc/mysql/my.cnf" datadir="/mnt/eoacluster/mysql" \
binary="/usr/bin/mysqld_safe" pid="/var/run/mysql/mysql.pid" \
socket="/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock" log="/var/log/mysql/mysql.log" \
additional_parameters="--bind-address=192.168.1.254" \
    op start interval="0" timeout="120s" \
    op stop interval="0" timeout="120s" \
    op monitor interval="15s" user="mysql" group="mysql"

primitive virtual_ip ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 \
    params ip="192.168.1.254" nic="eth1" \
    op monitor interval="10s" \
meta is-managed="true"

group res_group virtual_ip fs_drbd mysql_eoa \
meta target-role="Started"

ms ms_drbd drbd_eoa \
    meta master-max="1" master-node-max="1" \
clone-max="2" clone-node-max="1" notify="true" \
target-role="Started"

location master-prefer-EOA-MAIL-IB-1 virtual_ip 25: EOA-MAIL-IB-1

colocation res_group_on_drbd_eoa inf: res_group ms_drbd:Master

order res_group_after_ms_drbd inf: ms_drbd:promote res_group:start

property $id="cib-bootstrap-options" \
    dc-version="1.0.8-042548a451fce8400660f6031f4da6f0223dd5dd" \
    cluster-infrastructure="openais" \
    expected-quorum-votes="2" \
    stonith-enabled="false" \
    no-quorum-policy="ignore" \
    last-lrm-refresh="1336683121"
```